# database submission to postgres from HTML form

Tags: django

I want to submit data from html for to database(postgresql).I am using  django as I learn it.I get the following error after clicking submit button.

[image: error]

The form is  :

```html
<form action="\polls\Registration" method="POST">
              <div class="form-group mb15">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userName" placeholder="Enter Your Username" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group mb15">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Enter Your Password">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group mb15">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullName" placeholder="Enter Your Full Name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group mb20">
                <label class="ckbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
                  <span>Accept terms and conditions</span>
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-quirk btn-block">Create Account</button>
                <br>
                <a href="/polls/signin" class="btn btn-default btn-quirk btn-stroke btn-stroke-thin btn-block btn-sign">Already a member? Sign In Now!</a>
              </div>
            </form>
```

model is:

```html
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.db import models
from django import forms

class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body_text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    mod_date = models.DateField()
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    n_comments = models.IntegerField()
    n_pingbacks = models.IntegerField()
    rating = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.headline

class Registration(models.Model):
 userName=forms.CharField(max_length=200)
 password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
 fullName=forms.CharField(max_length=250)
```

urls.py

```html
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from . import myview 
from . import view
from . import models
from django.conf.urls import include,url
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', myview.index,name='index'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.model_activation.urls')),
    #url(r'^$',myview.index1, name='index1'),
    #url(r'^$',view.index2, name='index2'),
    url(r'^index', myview.index,name='index'),
    url(r'^index2', myview.index2,name='index2'),
    url(r'^signup', myview.signup,name='signup'),
    url(r'^signin', myview.signin,name='signin'),
    url(r'^logiin', myview.login,name='login'),
    url(r'^auth', myview.auth_view,name='auth_view'),
    url(r'^signout', myview.signout,name='signout'),
    url(r'^Registration', models.Registration,name='Registration'),
]
```

After I submit,the details are not submitted to database table also.

Please where is the bug?Any hint?

Comment: Great! Well good luck with it, remember you can always ask a descriptive question that includes what you have tried and researched on [so] if you get stuck!

Comment: I tried it out .Please check the edited code above

Comment: Please read [ask]. Also, your `Registration` class doesn't have any model fields - only form fields.

Comment: Ok.lemme do more research on it since am a newbie

Comment: Read how to create **views** and handle your form **requests** from them

Comment: I know how to create views and models.handling requests from views i what I have to research on.

Comment: Please check edited.Thats what I have tried but am getting an error

Comment: First, replace `forms.` with `models.` in your `Registration` model, second, the last line of your urlpatterns has to contain a **view**, not a **model** - `url(r'^Registration', models.Registration,name='Registration'), ` has to be `url(r'^registration', myviews.your_view,name='registration'),`

Comment: Should I change models.Model to forms.Form?

Comment: No. All your model fields (unless using third party modules to extend the  functionality) should start with 'models.'. All your models by default extend `models.Model`, not `forms.Form`

Comment: Ok so which forms should I replace with models the way you have suggested?

Comment: Everything within your `class Registration`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a registration view.

The url() function expects a view, and will call the get function on that view. 
At present you are giving the registration url a model to run. Its trying to run the get method, but your model doesn't have one, hence the error.

in your view file try something along the lines of:

```
class RegistrationView(FormView):
    model = Registration
    template_name = 'path to your tamplate here'
    def get(self, *args, **kwrags):
         # code here to display the empty form
    def post(self, *args, **kwrags):
         # code here to handle the request with a populated form.
```

That example is for a class based FormView. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview

It might be easier to use a function based view to begin with (more typing, less 'magic').
Probably its a  good idea to read through the relevant documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/